# JavaFX ListChangeListener removals triggers an addition change

Tags: java, javafx

I need an explanation as to why it behaves this way
and the solution how to best solve this.

I have a custom JavaFX control. The Model has a list of data which is used to build the control in the View. I also have a Behaviour that will remove overflow of the list, based on a limit set on how many values there should be in the list and shown in the control. When items in the list is removed it should then remove those from the View.
In an MVC, the Control is the Model, the Skin is the View, and Behaviour the controller.

```
public class CustomControl
public class CustomControlSkin
public class CustomControlBehavior
```

I have a ListChangeListener added to the model data, which listens for additions and removals. New values are added to the control, while removals should be removed from it.

I have created a SSCCE that illustrates the problem. I first used a timer in the example to simulate the receiving of data which comes in a different thread than the JavaFX thread. In my application I have a async service the delivers this data. However the example works to illustrate the problem even without the Timer, but I wanted to keep it there.

For simplicity the Example just creates an Label for each value in the model, and it creates 30 values at first. Since the limit is set to 10, the control is actually only supposed to display 10, but actually displays the 10 + the 30.

```
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Timer;
import java.util.TimerTask;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.application.Platform;
import javafx.collections.FXCollections;
import javafx.collections.ListChangeListener;
import javafx.collections.ObservableList;
import javafx.scene.Node;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class TestListRemovals extends Application {

    private VBox root = new VBox();

    private ObservableList<String> values = FXCollections.observableList(new LinkedList<String>());

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        TestListRemovals.launch(args);
    }

    /* (non-Javadoc)
     * @see javafx.application.Application#start(javafx.stage.Stage)
     */
    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
        Scene scene = new Scene(root, 400, 600);
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();

        values.addListener(new ListChangeListener<String>() {

            @Override
            public void onChanged(Change<? extends String> change) {
                System.out.println("onChanged");
                while (change.next()) {
                    System.out.println("change wasAdded " + change.wasAdded());
                    System.out.println("change wasPermutated " + change.wasPermutated());
                    System.out.println("change wasRemoved " + change.wasRemoved());
                    System.out.println("change wasReplaced " + change.wasReplaced());
                    System.out.println("change wasUpdated " + change.wasUpdated());
                    if (change.wasAdded()) {
                        System.out.println("Added " + change.getAddedSize());
                        addValues(change.getAddedSubList());
                    }

                    if (change.wasRemoved()) {
                        System.out.println("Removed " + change.getRemovedSize());
                        removeValues(change.getRemoved());
                    }
                    removeOverflow();
                }
            }

        });

        Timer delay = new Timer();
        delay.schedule(new TimerTask() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                List<String> newValues = new LinkedList<>();
                for (int i = 1; i < 31; i++) {
                    final String value = "Value " + i;
                    newValues.add(value);
                }
                Platform.runLater(() -> {
                    values.addAll(newValues);
                });
            }

        }, 2000);

    }

    public void removeOverflow() {
        System.out.println("removeOverflow");
        final int limit = 10;
        final int size = values.size();
        final int overflow = size - limit;
        if (overflow > 0) {
            System.out.println("Remove from 0 to " + overflow);
            values.remove(0, overflow);
        }
    }

    public void addValues(List<? extends String> values) {
        values.forEach(value -> {
            final Label label = new Label(value);
            root.getChildren().add(0, label);
        });
    }

    public void removeValues(List<? extends String> values) {
        values.forEach(value -> {
            for (Iterator<Node> itr = root.getChildren().iterator(); itr.hasNext();) {
                final Node node = itr.next();
                if (node instanceof Label) {
                    if (((Label) node).getText().equals(value)) {
                        itr.remove();
                    }
                }
            }
        });
    }

}
```

The removal is actually triggering an addition of the remaining in the list, not the removed items.

I can fix this by wrapping the removal within a JavaFX Task to execute on a different thread. However that does not feel like it is a proper solution to the problem.
Also Why is the removal actually triggering a second addition, not of the items removed, but the remaining items?

Edit: Seems it is not recommended to change the list from within the ListChangeListener. Any suggestion how I can change the list outside of the ListChangeListener which is triggered from an addition?
I tried with an JavaFX Task to call the removal, which works, but it kinda seem like overkill to have a thread within a custom control for each update of its data.

Comment: Note you're calling `removeOverflow()` from inside the `ListChangeListener` which modifies the source list while processing the change—you [shouldn't do that](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/13/javafx.base/javafx/collections/ListChangeListener.Change.html). I don't know if that's the cause of your problem, however.

Comment: I suspected that was the case.
The thing is I want to remove overflow of the list based on a limit. Currently I am checking for overflow when new values are added. If thee is an overflow then remove those.

Comment: You could try wrapping the modifying code in a `Platform.runLater` call.

Comment: That also works. I kinda was hoping for a solution where a Plarform.runLater was unnecessary. The removal happens within my CustomControlBehavior, which is called from my CustomControlSkin in the ObservableList's ListChangeListener.

Comment: Looking through Stack Overflow the only related Q&A I could find is [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46219356/6395627), and the answer gives `runLater` as a solution. I suppose you could try creating an `ObservableList` decorator that removes any overflow after adding elements. This could be tedious, however, as there are at least three ways to add elements to a list: via the list itself, via a sub-list, and via a `ListIterator`. Another option, if you can strictly control access to the `ObservableList`, is to simply call `removeOverflow()` after calling any of the add methods.